# Guarda de rotas com evento assíncrono

Tags: angular, rotas

Tenho uma guarda de rotas que verifica se o usuário está logado a partir de um token no localStorage que funciona muito bem. Porém ele não espera nenhum evento assíncrono. Preciso criar uma nova guarda de rotas que verifica se o usuário é administrador. Para isso eu faço uma consulta na API que me informa a situação do usuário.

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable <boolean> | boolean {
    let admin;
    admin = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.adminService.isAdmin(userId).toPromise().then(
            res => {
                if (res.isAdmin) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
        );
    });
    return admin;
}
```

O retorno da api está certo, mas a função não espera a resposta por tanto não consigo fazer funcionar. Alguma ideia para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o erro apenas usando o resolve.
Mais explicações nesse link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEUSrpsAPtw